# PHP NumberFormatter removing the .00

Tags: php

Trying to remove the last .00 from a currency formatted using PHP NumberFormatter but it doesn't seem possible. I can see this option but it doesn't seem to affect a currency: `DECIMAL_ALWAYS_SHOWN`

```
$nf = new \NumberFormatter('en_US', \NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
$nf->formatCurrency(0, 'EUR');
// Output is €0.00 but it doesn't seem possible to remove the .00
```

I would do a str_replace for .00 but this may be different depending on locale so it doesn't seem that easy.

Comment: Divide it by 1. For example echo "1.00"/1; prints 1.

Comment: @karmafunk Interesting... never knew about that!

Comment: Yeah but it is a string it has the Euro symbol on it.

Comment: try to use  `number_format($number);` function

Comment: did you try `public bool NumberFormatter::setPattern ( string $pattern )`

Comment: $nf = `str_replace('.00','',$nf);`

Answer (score 7):

You can force that only with the `format()` method:

```
$nf = new \NumberFormatter('en_US', \NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
$nf->setTextAttribute(\NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_CODE, 'EUR');
$nf->setAttribute(\NumberFormatter::MAX_FRACTION_DIGITS, 0);
echo $nf->format(1);
```

Comment: This doesn't work as asked : it rounds up/down the number. Try
`$nf->format(10.50)` and you won't get 10.50 but **10**

Answer (score 1):

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

/**
 * Format a float value into a formatted number with currency,
 * depending on the locale and the currency code.
 */
function customCurrencyFormatter(float $value, ?string $locale = 'en_US', ?string $currencyCode = 'EUR'): string {
    // Init number formatter and its default settings.
    $nf = new \NumberFormatter($locale ?? Locale::getDefault(), \NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
    $nf->setTextAttribute(\NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_CODE, $currencyCode);

    // Apply number rules. Here, we round it at the number of decimals 
    // we want to display on non-integer values. 
    // Examples.
    //   2 decimals: 1.949 -> 1.95
    //   3 decimals: 1.9485 -> 1.949
    $value = \round($value, $nf->getAttribute(\NumberFormatter::MIN_FRACTION_DIGITS));
    // Detect if the rounded result is an integer value.
    // If so, remove decimals from the formatting.
    if (\intval($value) == $value) {
      $nf->setAttribute(\NumberFormatter::MIN_FRACTION_DIGITS, 0);
    }

    // Convert non-breaking and narrow non-breaking spaces to normal ones.
    return \str_replace(["\xc2\xa0", "\xe2\x80\xaf"], ' ', $nf->format($value));
}


echo customCurrencyFormatter(2.999, 'de_DE', 'USD') . \PHP_EOL;
// 3 $
echo customCurrencyFormatter(2.949, 'de_DE', 'USD') . \PHP_EOL;
// 2,95 $
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that the MIN_FRACTION_DIGITS attribute will allow you to suppress unwanted zeroes like this:

```
$nf = new \NumberFormatter('en_US', \NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
$nf->setAttribute( \NumberFormatter::MIN_FRACTION_DIGITS, 0 );
$nf->formatCurrency(0, 'EUR');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$nf = new \NumberFormatter('en_US', \NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
$nf->formatCurrency(0, 'EUR');
numfmt_set_attribute($nf, \NumberFormatter::MAX_FRACTION_DIGITS, 0);
echo numfmt_format($nf, 123.00)."\n";
```

Comment: As far I understand MAX_FRACTION_DIGITS will limit the maximum displayed decimals and will also clear them even if they are non-zero.

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking to remove `.00` only and willing to keep it if there is other than `.00` then you could try:

```
$formatter = new \NumberFormatter('en_US', \NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
$money =  $formatter->formatCurrency($money, 'USD');
$money = rtrim($money,".00");
```

In case, if you are looking to round all those numbers after decimals you can add `round`:

```
$formatter = new \NumberFormatter('en_US', \NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
$money =  $formatter->formatCurrency(round($money,0), 'USD');
```

you could also use `floor` and `ceil` instead of the round if you need lower and upper value respectively.

Answer (score -3):

cant you do it with round()?

```
echo round($nf, 0)
```

Comment: The returned value is a string as it contains the currency symbol in there.